# React Native configuration for existing Android project

Tags: android, react-native

I'am trying to integrate React Native to my existing Android app using the newest React Native version of 0.45.1.

The project setup is standard as created by the `init` command. In the android subfolder I checked out my existing Android app and followed the steps from [Integration With Existing Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html)

When running `react-native run-android` its gets me:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

This is obviously due to my non standard Android project structure as I have several modules and my main module is not named `app`.

Now the actual question: Is there a way to configure the React Native layer and to tell it where my Manifest and possibly other required files reside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got is, pretty simple actually. `--help` is your friend.

```
--appFolder [string]      Specify a different application folder name for the android source.
```

is exactly what I was looking for. For anyone who has similar troubles, there are some other interesting options as well.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better that what you have done to resolve this issue.

Comment: react-native run-android --appFolder <projectName>. I changed my project name from app to myapp, so I ran "react-native run-android --appFolder myapp" and it worked.